# How to get the total values of each textboxes without pressing any buttons?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am creating an expense tracking report using Visual Studio 2010 C# where the user can see the total of all the expenses while he/she is still typing the values for each expenses so that he/she could know if the total is equivalent or higher than her budget. My question is, how can I get the total of all the expenses the user is entering without having him/her press any button to calculate? Please help. Thanks

This is the screenshot of the form:

[image]

This is the code:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tot = 0;
        tot += int.Parse(textBox1.Text); // No error checking, just an example
        tot += double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        textBox3.Text = tot.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should catch `TextChange` event on every textbox (it could be one for all)

```
double tot = 0;
private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update sum here
    tot = 0;
    tot += Int.Parse(Textbox1.Text); // No error checking, just an example
    tot += Double.Parse(Textbox2.Text); // Be careful to decimal separator

    TotalTextBox.Text = tot.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Does tb_textchanged is the name of my Total textbox?

Comment: @sean: no, it's a functions you can set to be used for every textbox. You can do that in Property tab of every textbox or by code `TextBox1.TextChanged += tb_TextChanged;` and so on...

Comment: @sean: this method makes total computed everytime user changes anything in each textbox, so doing exactly what you're asking ;)

Comment: Where can I specify what textbox that I want the total of all the values I want to display? Should I put the functions in all of the textboxes?

Comment: No @sean: you should set `TextChanged` event of every textbox to `tb_TextChanged`, with Property tab on VS user interface, or by code as I told you in my previous comment... In `tb_TextChanged()` you can sum every textbox value you want, just complete my example

Comment: I've tried your code but then there is no values displayed in my total textbox. I only tried to put value on the Meal textbox, I entered 20 so I expected that the Total textbox will display 20. But then there is value displayed. What can you say about this? Please.

Comment: @sean: look at my edited post and tell me if you understand it

Comment: Thank you! I got it now. By the way, what if I want the other textbox will be deducted with the previous values? should I just "+=" to "-="?

Comment: @sean: no, you can use send them to same function; then using `TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender` you can know which textbox was modified...

Comment: Why is it when I tried to add a new value for 2nd textbox which is for transportation there is an error occured stating that "Input string was not in a correct format."?

Comment: @sean: Probably because you're using a double, not an integer. Look at my edited post in a minute...

Comment: Can you tell me which text are you trying to insert? I cannot guess it... ;) And which error are you getting now?

Comment: i tried to insert where I specified the Double.Parse and the error occured there stating that "Input string was not in a correct format.".

Comment: @sean: I cannot guess things: show me text you are inserting please and which language is your OS.

Comment: I am using windows 7. I just updated my question and posted the code. Please check.

Comment: @sean: first, why do you use two separate functions? Use one, the same. Second: you didn't post the text you're inserting taht causes the error...

Comment: I already removed the second function I created. It worked but the total will only display whenever I try to input number on the total textbox. Is there something I can do that it will automatically display the total everytime I enter values on other textboxes?

Comment: @sean: I've already told you several times: set `TextChange` event of every textbox you want to control to `tb_TextChanged()`!!

Comment: I'm so sorry. I got it working now. I can't make deletion after I entered values, right? Is there any way I can make it happen? So everytime I input wrong numbers I can alter it.

Comment: @sean: yes, you can. Using `TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender` you can check `tb.Text` and do what you please with it.

Comment: I've tried this "TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;", but then when I changed the value the total doesn't update it's sum.